# Hi, I am creating a web page using bootstrap

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I devoleped a web page which have content in grid form.col-sm-2 and col-sm-10.I want to hide content of col-sm-2 when it become a mobile app.and show and hide it using an icon. please give me an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: You want to use collapsing classes, which is perfectly documented at [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) and a bunch of tutorial sites [like this one](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/).
Consider taking the [tour at Stack Overflow's Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an overview of what you should and shouldn't ask here.

Answer (score 0):

try using jQuery Mobile Panels Check the doc [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel/)